# How does EMI affect a circuit?

Tags: power-supply, pcb, high-voltage, protection, interference

I was designing pcbs and my head engineer told me that if input supply is large then there should be a separate layer for ground and positive supply as this will reduce EMI effects on the nearby components.

What exactly EMI does to a component such as an inductor?  May be induce voltage and cause the component to burn out or change the filters characteristics ?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: People write tons of books that answer this question, maybe you can narrow it down so it can be answered in this sites format.

Comment: Might even be beneficial to talk to your head engineer to give you some insight.

Comment: @PlasmaHH any rough idea would be help full

Comment: @TaimoorAli: a rough idea is that you have capacitive and inductive coupling between all your components.

Comment: I have doubts about what you have interpreted from your head engineer. A power supply needn't be "large" to justify separate layers in a PCB so go back the the guy and properly understand what he was telling you because at the moment it makes no sence.

Comment: Can you please provide us with some more specifics with regard to the project? This will help the audience formulate a quality response. EMI is a very broad topic. The following question and response might give you some insight [Is interference between aircraft an issue for fly-by-wireless technology?](http://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/2071/is-interference-between-aircraft-an-issue-for-fly-by-wireless-technology/2092#2092)

Comment: @Taimoor Ali: Short and complete answer: the effects of electrical charges, currents, electric and magnetic fields is described by Maxwell's Equations.

Comment: appreciate that

Answer (score 1):

having a dedicated GND/Vcc plane has dual benifits.

1) It acts as a thermal spreader thereby acting as a natural coolant for your PCB.

2) Reducing EMI. 
All signals are referenced to GND on your board. Having a constant ground plane below your signals gives you a clean signal. Another advantage of having GND planes is that they sink in EMI generated by high noise generated sections. Imagine you have tracks ,say on the edge. Suppose there is interference from other sections of your system. It corrupts the signals of those tracks. But if you have a GND pour/layer shielding it the GND absorbs the EMI thereby nullifying its effects.
In other words the GND plane acts as a shield that sink EMI.

Many antenna vendors recommend a GND pour (Stitched) near the antenna section.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, unless you have misunderstood your head engineer, or you are doing very high frequency operation, he was being careless. The primary use of ground planes is to a) reduce the effects of iR drops between points due to current flow and b) minimize inductive effects of current transitions. Both of these can cause real problems, particularly when they occur between the ground points of different components. Look up "ground loops". Using power planes instead of traces is also a good idea, since they prevent these same effects from causing variations in power supply voltage, although it's easier to overcome these effects by incorporating decoupling capacitors in the circuit than it is to overcome ground noise/ground loop problems. Except at extremely high frequencies, of course, where *everything* is a problem.

At very high frequencies, it is true that ground and power planes serve to prevent signals radiating to adjacent traces, but this is only part of the problem. At such frequencies, ground planes are at least as important in defining the characteristic impedance of the traces carrying signals, and cross-talk (while important) is generally less of an issue.

Answer (score 0):

All electrical/electronic circuits receive input electrical signals and generate electrical output signals that is meaningful to users. For example a basic radio in all case has inputs of AC/DC power supply and a RF signal. The user tunes the radio to a radio station and adjust the volume to generate sound as output. (Common Knowledge)

Now lets assume that the radio is in the vicinity of a motor. Example a inside an automotive. Automotive have motors, such wipe motors, an alternator, motor based pumps and other components that a magnetic based. These components generate Electromagnetic signals, which electrical engineers to a the most part refer to as noise. The case of a radios inside an automotive, engineers strategically place an inductor base filter circuit along the power supply line to attenuate any undesirable signal (Also known as electromagnetic noise) that will affect the user experience. In this case sound generate by a radio.

Above is a basics common example for EMI.

**References:**

- [The Basics of Noise Filtering](http://espei.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/ESP-White-Paper-The-Basics-of-Noise-Filtering.pdf)
- [Basics of Noise Countermeasures [Lesson 1] What is an EMI filter?](http://www.murata.com/en-us/products/emiconfun/emc/2010/10/28/en-20101028-p1)
- [Is interference between aircraft an issue for fly-by-wireless technology?](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/2071/is-interference-between-aircraft-an-issue-for-fly-by-wireless-technology/2092#2092)